# How can I create a serialized transaction that can be submitted to the blockchain without a local full node?

Tags: transaction, blockfrost

My goal is to send a transaction (e.g. send 1 ADA from addr1A to addr1B) using the following endpoint of the blockfrost.io API:

> "Submit an already serialized transaction to the network."
>
> [https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/~1tx~1submit/post](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/%7E1tx%7E1submit/post)

It requires a serialized transaction. How can I create a serialized transaction without a local full node? (With a full node this could be done using the [cardano-cli](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/transaction-metadata/how-to-create-a-metadata-transaction-cli/#submit-to-blockchain)).

The [emurgo/message-signing](https://github.com/Emurgo/message-signing) library seems to provide this functionality but I'm not sure how to use it. The [example](https://github.com/Emurgo/message-signing/blob/master/examples/rust/src/main.rs) they provide just signs some random string.

Are there any other libraries that can be used for this?

The library would need to be able to

1. Create a transaction (with metadata)
2. Calculate the fees
3. Sign/serialize the transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [cardanosharp-wallet](https://github.com/CardanoSharp/cardanosharp-wallet) library that provides this functionality. They have a section in their [README.md](https://github.com/CardanoSharp/cardanosharp-wallet#build-and-sign-transactions) that explains signing transactions.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @eddex's answer, another option would be to use the Emurgo's *cardano-serialization-lib*. There are not many examples available in their documentation, unfortunately.

Link: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib

For a guideline on how to use the library specifically for creating transactions, I found a good example in the *blockfrost-js* repository. The usage of *cardano-serialization-lib* can be found in one of the helper files.

Link: https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-js/blob/fb9a55fee07927f8d7c8b0a5aa9efd2d3daf6c77/examples/simple-transaction/src/index.ts